# How select remaining unspecified columns

Tags: mysql

I am looking to overwrite a column name in a table with an existing column name. 
I am Looking for a way to get the remaining unspecified columns in the tables.

> **Note:** 
>   The query could have more joins in the future.

eg

***Person***

```
+-----------+----------+---------+
| firstname | lastname | pers_id |
+-----------+----------+---------+
| Joe       | Soap     |       1 |
| Bobby     | Pin      |       2 |
| Janet     | Jackson  |       3 |
+-----------+----------+---------+
```

***Category***

```
+----------+-------------------+--------+
|   type   |    description    | cat_id |
+----------+-------------------+--------+
| customer | people who pay us |      1 |
| employee | people we pay     |      2 |
| director | people who direct |      3 |
+----------+-------------------+--------+
```

***Person_Cat***
(=^ェ^=)

```
+---------+--------+
| pers_id | cat_id |
+---------+--------+
|       3 |      1 |
|       2 |      2 |
|       1 |      3 |
+---------+--------+
```

***Query***

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(p.firstname, ' '
        , p.lastname) as full_name
        , c.cat_id AS category_id
        ,  p.pers_id AS cat_id
FROM Person AS p 
JOIN Person_Cat AS pc ON(p.pers_id = pc.pers_id) 
JOIN Category AS c ON (pc.cat_id = c.cat_id)
```

***OUTPUT***
(*Apologies for the length but the table after is more important*)

```
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+---------------+-------------+--------+
|      p    |     p    |     p   |    pc   |    pc  |     c    |          c        |    c   |     Select    |    Select   | Select |
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+---------------+-------------+--------+
| firstname | lastname | pers_id | pers_id | cat_id |   type   |    description    | cat_id |   full_name   | category_id | cat_id |
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+---------------+-------------+--------+
| Janet     | Jackson  |       3 |       3 |      1 | customer | people who pay us |      1 | Janet jackson |           1 |      3 |
| Bobby     | Pin      |       2 |       2 |      2 | employee | people who we pay |      2 | Bobby Pin     |           2 |      2 |
| Joe       | Soap     |       1 |       1 |      3 | director | people who direct |      3 | Joe Soap      |           3 |      1 |
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------+----------+-------------------+--------+---------------+-------------+--------+
```

The headers above column names are there for reference 
to where they comes from.

*Column summary -*

`firstname`, `lastname`, `pers_id`, `pers_id`, `cat_id`, `type`,

`description`, `cat_id`, `full_name` ,`category_id`, `cat_id`

***Wanted output***

```
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+--------+
|      p    |     p    |    pc   |    pc  |     c    |          c        |     Select    |    Select   | Select |
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+--------+
| firstname | lastname | pers_id | cat_id |   type   |    description    |   full_name   | category_id | cat_id |
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+--------+
| Janet     | Jackson  |       3 |      1 | customer | people who pay us | Janet jackson |           1 |      3 |
| Bobby     | Pin      |       2 |      2 | employee | people who we pay | Bobby Pin     |           2 |      2 |
| Joe       | Soap     |       1 |      3 | director | people who direct | Joe Soap      |           3 |      1 |
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+----------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+--------+
```

*Column summary -*

`firstname`, `lastname`, `pers_id`, `cat_id`, `type`,

`description`, `full_name` ,`category_id`, `cat_id`

> ***Notice:***
>   The *`p.pers_id`* and the *`c.cat_id`* are not present. I would like to think this would be because the were called directly and unmodified unlike the `first` and `lastname` used in ConCat

Comment: Stop using `SELECT *` and use only the columns you are interested in.

Comment: @MikeBrant most important reason i do not want to get rid of `Select * ` is because this table is set to get more columns in future updates. I can handle this feature not being here. will just be more code

Comment: Well, then you will need to deal with duplicate columns. I don't understand why you are specifically selecting some columns that would show up in your `SELECT *` anyway.  You are in essence contributing to the problem you are looking to resolve. It is actually a good thing to specify actual columns you want to use instead of `SELECT *`.  Think of a case where some new columns are added.  If you use `SELECT *` throughout your codebase, you have no idea where an added column may introduce a bug.  With explicitly named columns you could add new columns without impacting other areas.

Comment: Continuing from previous comment...   That is because areas in your code that don't need to use that new column would not need to be changed and thus would simply act as if the new columns didn't exist.  You are also adding more overhead to your query.  By selecting every column in a table, even ones you aren't going to directly use, you are adding to bandwidth to transfer that data.  CHeck this thread out for more reading - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/234657/why-is-select-from-table-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @MikeBrant that is why i was asking if there was a `Select [remaining columns]` option. I'm trying to avoid having duplicat columns here. u have misunderstood my goal here completely. for displaying a tbale any new columns need to be there as well as necessary columns that the system require

Comment: @Sarfarazz When the short answer is that there is no such concept as `Select [remaining columns]` so if you want to use `SELECT *` but only remove redundant columns, then you will need to explicitly remove (ignore) those redundant columns when rendering your view. You will have to explicitly configure logic of which columns to ignore, which is pretty much the same thing as explicitly listing the columns that you are interested in, so you get back to the argument against selecting all columns that I made above.Unless your table schema is changing all the time, there really isn't reason for this

Comment: @MikeBrant alright. if you put that as an answer I will mark it as the answer since the feature does not exist yet

Comment: @Safaraaz That is a feature that will, in all likelihood, never exist.

Comment: I'm interested in the same feature to select remaining columns using some special select remaining operator like double asterisk **, because there are times when you want the most relevant columns from multiple tables for analysis displayed in the results before the least relevant columns from those tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the short answer is that there is no such concept as `Select [remaining columns]`at    this time (2015-06-17), if you want to use `SELECT *` but **only remove redundant columns**,
 then you will need to explicitly remove (ignore) those redundant columns when rendering your view.

You will have to explicitly configure logic of which columns to ignore, which is pretty much the same thing as explicitly listing the columns that you are interested in, so you get back to the argument against selecting all columns that I made in the comments above.

Unless your table schema is **changing all the time**, there really isn't reason for this.